# How can I implement continuous deployment with docker and PWA on local network?

Tags: reactjs, docker, localhost, continuous-deployment

I am working on three progressive web apps (PWA) which will run on three different computers and on one of the computers there will be docker running. All those PWA's are currently being updated via docker since they are docker images. Currently, they all run on one PC but eventually as mentioned above they will be on three different PC's. They all will be in the same local network.

The PWA's are made with React.js. Is it possible to continue updating those PWA's via docker since they will be now on different PC's but in the same network or I have to upload the PWA's on a server?

The apps are not meant to be accessible by everybody on the internet but only locally. I hope I get get some guidance on my challenge. Thanks in advance.

Comment: How are you deploying now (on to the three systems; in Docker specifically)?  What problems are you worried about running into if you use Docker everywhere?

Comment: I don't understand how I will run docker and the PWA's on different PC's but still communicate with each other ( in the same local network).